# Get name of the second CSS class with JQuery onclick

Tags: jquery

This is a simple div with two classes:

```
<div class="social twitter"></div>
```

I am trying to get the name of the second class onclick:

```
$( ".social" ).bind( "click touchstart", function() {
        var sn = $(this).**SECOND_CLASS(= twitter)**;

    });
```

any ideas on how this could be done? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which will return list of class attributes of the element.

```js
$(".social").bind("click touchstart", function() {
  var cName = this.classList[1];
  alert(cName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social twitter">Hello</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5332dx8x/)

Comment: Never go away from **Vanilla JS**, it makes life easier.. :)

Answer (score 5):

May help
you can use this code if you have just one space between classes

```
$( ".social" ).on( "click touchstart", function() {
        var sn = ($(this).attr('class').split(' '))[1];
         alert(sn);
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/phgqfauh/)

and if you have more spaces between classes you can use .. and I think it will be better

```
$( ".social" ).on( "click touchstart", function() {
        var sn = ($(this).attr('class').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' '))[1];
         alert(sn);
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/phgqfauh/2/)

Comment: @Rossitten you welcome .. Good Luck :) .. I just tried to searching for something right now the if you have more than one space between classes .. I find the answer .. I will update the code